# Convert DateTime and Boolean to string

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm a complete C# novice, please excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to parse string values into a view-model. I'm having difficulty converting the database DateTime and Boolean values into strings as part of the LineOne, LineTwo and LineThree properties. How do I do this?

```
private void mapChecks() 
{
    bool FoundResult = false;

    // Check if object is loaded
    if (Items.Count == 0)
    {
    //Add everything
        foreach (xtn_UnresolvedCheck check in MyChecks)
        {
                Items.Add(new ItemViewModel
                    {

                        LineOne = check.ClientName,
                        LineTwo = check.NSMDateTime,
                        LineThree = check.HaveRead,
                        MyappId = check.MonitoringID

          }
        );
    }
}
```

ItemViewModel:

```
namespace App
{
    public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _myappId;

        public int MyappId
        {
            get
            {
                return _myappId;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _myappId)
                {
                    _myappId = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyappId");
                }
            }
        }

    private bool _isFavorite;

    public bool IsFavorite
    {
        get
        {
            return _isFavorite;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isFavorite)
            {
                _isFavorite = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsFavorite");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineOne;

    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineTwo;

    public string LineTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineTwo)
            {
                _lineTwo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineTwo");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineThree;

    public string LineThree
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineThree;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineThree)
            {
                _lineThree = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineThree");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a simple `.ToString()` after those properties help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this

```
 Items.Add( new ItemViewModel
 {

        LineOne = check.ClientName,
        LineTwo = check.NSMDateTime.ToString(),
        LineThree = check.HaveRead.ToString(),
        MyappId = check.MonitoringID
 });
```

Comment: Was our answer helped you?

Comment: No string is displayed if I do that, does that mean there is a problem in the ItemViewModel.

Comment: Please add more info about you viewmodel.

Comment: Did you check check.NSMDateTime is null or ..?

Comment: Did you try and debug and see what do you get after using the .ToString() to the properties? What are the values the properties hold after you assign the .ToString() version of them? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToString();`

or cast to string